# how to become the preview stream in RAW Format (Camera2 API , ImageFormate.RAW_SENSOR)?

Tags: android, preview, camera2

Hello I have a really difficult question. **I got the nexus 6 and I want to have the preview stream in RAW fromat** (ImageFormate.RAW_SENSOR) **at the camera2 API**. *Is this even possible*?

I use the android-Camera2Raw (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not possible. Please see this table for a list of formats possible as a stream: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP

Your most "raw" choice would be turning off noise reduction (if supported by the hardware) in your `CaptureRequest.Builder`, like so:

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE, CaptureRequest.NOISE_REDUCTION_MODE_OFF);
```

If frame rate isn't an issue, you could send repeated CaptureRequests for RAW images, and on your `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener()` process the RAW, convert it to a Bitmap, then place that into an `ImageView`, but that approach is exactly as impractical as it sounds :)